# What is intuition behind sets with more sums than differences?

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

There exist finite sets $A$ in, say, $\mathbb{Z}$, such that $|A+A|>|A-A|$. The minimal such set contains 8 elements and consists of, say, 0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 12, 14. How should I find such an example without computer search? Is there some implicit argument why such sets should exist? For example, (non-convex, of course) set on the plane with analogous property for area automatically provides finite examples for $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and thus for $\mathbb{Z}$6 are there some nice natural polygons with this property? Quick search of constructions of such sets shows that they all start with explicit examples like the above.

Comment: Nathanson's paper "Sets with more sums than differences" may contain some answers. At least, it contains further references (looking at Ruzsa's paper on the subject may be particularly insightful).

Comment: @Seva this is a nice paper, it suggests that it is natural to look at almost symmetric sets $A$. Well, it really is, and less-or-more-quickly leads to an example, but maybe there are some more conceptual insights.

Comment: Maybe this is more conceptual for you: there is no reason to expect this inequality modulo a prime $p$ for large sets. Take a large set of such primes and counterexamples for them, and use Chinese remainder theorem to obtain a really bad set modulo some $n$. Then we can stop pretending working mod $n$, which loses us a factor of only $2$. So, the inequality fails because it fails locally for (almost) every prime

Comment: @BorisBuch great, this is what I need!